# CMAKE building for cygwin

Tags: cygwin, cmake

I used CMAKE to create the Visual Studios C++ project for a library that I needed to build, and then I used VC++ to build the library.  However, the time has come to rebuild the same library for cygwin so that I can link to it with the GNU tool chain (g++ make gdb).  I've been trying to figure out how to configure CMAKE to build for cygwin but I'm not getting very far.  I've checked the CMAKE website for help (and I will continue to search around there), but I barely have a grasp on what CMAKE really is, so I am having trouble finding the answers.  Can anyone point me in a better direction? (Thanks, All.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CMake is a build system.  It's designed to let you write a single cross-platform build description, then it creates platform-specific build files (such as makefiles for the GNU toolchain) from that build setup.

To make it work under Cygwin, it should suffice to install the `cmake` Cygwin package (using Cygwin's `setup.exe`) then run commands similar to the following:  (Since you'll be running CMake for Cygwin, you won't need to do anything to configure it for the GNU toolchain).

```
mkdir my-project-build
cd my-project-build
cmake /path/to/my-project
make
```

Comment: make sure to use separate build directories for your g++ and visual studio builds. Also a handy tip is that if you use the code blocks generator you can use qtcreator for editing and compilation.

Comment: That sounds promising, but upon running cmake I received the following errors:

    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake2.6.4/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:32 (MESSAGE):
    The C compiler "/usr/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program. It fails with the following output: Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/tmp/HyDE_Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

This error message doesn't make sense, "which gcc" provides the expected results, and I can compile and run a basic helloWorld.c  I'll keep this updated as I learn more.  THANKS!

Comment: That looks like cmake is having a user permission problem on entering or writing the test c file into that directory.I would also recommend upgrading to CMake 2.8

Comment: UPDATE: Fixed that problem.  Apparently cmake had found a gmake.exe in its path (thanks MATLAB) and was preferentially using it instead of make.  I deleted the MATLAB components from my path and that cleared up.

Comment: @josh How do we get the linux/unix executable file for this?.This process gives us a make file. when make is executed in cygwin the exe file is generated But this is for windows. How to crosscompile make? to generate unix executable file like the default.out .

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer: I've never done cross-compilation, so I can't help you, sorry.  CMake claims to support it, but I don't know any specifics.

Comment: @AdityaP: Ask another question for this please.