# FLANN compile (cygwin)

Tags: makefile, cmake, cygwin, nmake, flann

I'm trying to build FLANN libriary on windows.But I have cygwin installed.

```
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
> cd flann-x.y.z-src
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake ..
> nmake
```

and when I use `cmake ..` it seems it uses cygwin and gcc compiler.

and then `nmake` don't work.

Comment: have you tried "make" instead of nmake? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586210/cmake-building-for-cygwin

Comment: yes I tried.It seems work fine.But i think I need to use nmake to use windows *.dll and *.lib files.  Maybe problem is that it use cygwin cmake?

Answer (score 1):

Quite unclear what you want to achieve:

You can build FLANN in cygwin environment by cygwin's cmake and make and then [use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725660/2838364).

Or you can follow [FLANN installation instructions](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.8.4.pdf) and build it with window's native cmake and C++ compiler and use it (simply do not use cygwin at all, use cmd.exe).

In case you want to use VS2008 C++ compiler, do

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 9 2008" ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Comment: The problem is when I use cmake in cmd it uses gcc compiler and so on. I think it happens because cmake.exe is in C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin  and C:\cygwin\bin

Comment: in cmd.exe write 'where cmake' to see which one is used. Which C++ compiler & linker do you want to use?

Comment: where command don't work(can't find it), but which  gives /usr/bin/cmake in cygwin and cmd.I want to use VS2008 compiler.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\where.exe

Comment: Seems no where.exe in win xp http://superuser.com/questions/249725/where-to-download-where-exe-tool-for-windows-xp