# Cygwin:2.6.0-1 Failed to run CMake-3.3.2 for openGM which gives fatal error

Tags: c++, cmake, cygwin

I am having a problem while executing CMake command for OpenGM using cygwin bash which is installed in Windows 8.1 over my desktop machine. My machine has CMake (version 3.3.2) development wrapper by executing the cygwin.exe(version 2.6.0-1) which is 64bit. OpenGM is a C++ template library for discrete factor graph models and distributive operations on these models. I have downloaded the openGM from the sourceforge [opengm](https://github.com/opengm/opengm). By reading the different sources like [CMake building for cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586275/4031498) and followed the same procedure. First by going into the project directory folder then remaining codes were passed like:

```
mkdir my-project-build
cmake /path/to/my-project
make
```

I don't know how to build the OpenGM and run the platform/interface. The following error message after executing the bunch of lines showed:

```
In file included from /cygdrive/c/Users/Dell/Desktop/opengm-master/include/opengm/inference/auxiliary/fusion_move/fusion_mover.h          xx:16:0,
        from /cygdrive/c/Users/Dell/Desktop/opengm-master/include/opengm/inference/fusion_based_inf.hxx:38,
                     from /cygdrive/c/Users/Dell/Desktop/opengm-master/src/unittest/inference/test_fusion_based_inf.cxx:13:
    /cygdrive/c/Users/Dell/Desktop/opengm-master/include/opengm/inference/fix-fusion/fusion-move.hpp:6:29: fatal error: boost/foreac          h.hpp: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make[2]: *** [src/unittest/inference/CMakeFiles/test-fusion-based-inf.dir/build.make:63: src/unittest/inference/CMakeFiles/test-          fusion-based-inf.dir/test_fusion_based_inf.cxx.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3266: src/unittest/inference/CMakeFiles/test-fusion-based-inf.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:139: all] Error 2
```

Somebody help me regarding this error and how to build openGM for my work accordingly.

Comment: Please, make error log to be properly shown line by line. The simplest way is to format it as a code. Citation (lines beginning with `>`) makes the error log like a mess. As for the problem, `boost/foreach.hpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated. ` means that you have no Boost installed or it hasn't been found by the project.

Comment: You have a space in your include `boost/foreac h.hpp`.

Comment: I am newbie user in cygwin so I am unable to get what is boost/foreac h.hpp. Please help how can i fix this.