# CMake/cygwin and find_library not finding .lib library

Tags: c, cmake, cygwin, bonjour

I would like to use in my **cygwin** project **Bonjour library for Windows**. I have installed this library and I have `dnssd.lib` file but **CMake** doesn't find this library.

If I use this code:

```
  find_path(BONJOUR_PATH dns_sd.h
            PATHS "$ENV{BONJOUR_SDK_HOME}/Include")
    find_library(BONJOUR_LIBRARY
            NAMES dnssd.lib
            PATHS "$ENV{BONJOUR_SDK_HOME}/Lib/x64")
    include_directories(BONJOUR_PATH)
```

I am getting such error message:

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
>   they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
>   and tested correctly in the CMake files: BONJOUR_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)

It happens only when I wrap above code inside `if(CYGWIN) /* code */ endif()` but if I wrap it inside `if(WIN32) /* code */ endif()` then it finds library correctly.

Why this happens?

Comment: cygwin import library are `*.dll.a` not `*.lib`

Comment: But with Bonjour SDK I have delivered *.lib, so what should I do? Couldn't I mix unix libraries with native Windows libraries?

Comment: You should not mix different libraries. Or you use Unix convention or Windows one. Mixing is a recipe for mulfunction. It is specially true on 64 bit where also the data type convention are different. https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/programming.html#gcc-64

Comment: But dnssd.lib is 3rd party library so how I can use? Couldn't I use 3rd party libraries with cygwin?

Comment: Cygwin has that library. Install libdns_sd-devel package.  https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libdns_sd-devel/libdns_sd-devel-765.30.11-1

Comment: How can I install it?

Comment: I once had a similar problem when `cygwin` was using my Windows CMake version. Can you cross-check that you have the CMake Cygwin package installed (specialized CMake version for Cygwin, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586210/cmake-building-for-cygwin))?

Comment: Ok I found I can use Cygwin Setup :)  I forgot that there is such option to select packages/libraries

Answer (score 1):

While this answer may not apply to the OP's specific situation, I believe it does apply to the question.  In my case I'm using cmake & Cygwin, but am trying to run a cmake project that was originally done on Linux with cmake v2.8.  In my case, I'm using cmake v3.6.2, Cygwin v2.9.0-2, Windows 10.

To get cmake to find the libraries, I added this statement:

```
IF (CYGWIN)
  SET (CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES "")
  SET (CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".lib" ".LIB" ".dll" ".DLL")
ELSE()
  SET (CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES "lib")
  SET (CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".so" ".a")
ENDIF (CYGWIN)
```

Note that I added lib and dll in all caps, because while windows isn't case sensitive, cmake is.

Credit to Domen Vrankar for pointing out the prefix issue as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243524/cmake-find-library-matching-behavior)